# Sprite Animation for PNG [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, widget, sprite

I have a single PNG image(32px X 128px). Each 32px square contains a image as shown below.
[image]

What widget(s) should i use in flutter to provide this image as input and expect a GIF like animated image?

If that is not possible, how can i import few images(maybe 4 images) and display them one after the other inside the same Container, to make the image look like its animating?

Answer (score 1):

Use this package spritewidget  https://pub.dev/packages/spritewidget